# Chrome fps meter no longer shows frame rate

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, frame-rate

I'm trying to view my animation's frame rate in chrome using dev tools. The old FPS meter would actually show "Frame Rate", but it looks like the FPS meter has changed since then and no longer shows Frame Rate (I'm using Chrome 85).

[image: Here's how my FPS meter looks]

How do I get the old FPS meter that showed average frame rate?

Comment: you should ask a `chrome` support team. as a suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an chromium issue about it [[link]](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1124189), and it seems they have decided to remove the old fps meter and rename it to "Frame Rendering Stats" .

Answer (score 3):

**I find this on twitter . old fps meter is deleted i think**

https://twitter.com/addyosmani/status/1281483292026400768

Answer (score 0):

Open Performance tab and record, that also shows the rendering time.

Answer (score 0):

This has been re-instated, in Chrome builds 90.x and above. See the bottom of this post https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1124189